# read write to google spread sheet using api is free or paid

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I want to build a Java Application in order to read write google spreadsheet api.

On API Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) , I need to create project. So, I was not sure whether this task comes under any pricing from google after 60 days.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pages which might come handy for you:

- Quotas for document creation: https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard
- Quotas for queries: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

When you pass the quota, you will have to pay, otherwise application will become unusable (generally the requests are getting refused).